# Cannot read property 'parseMetaData' of undefined in Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I try to use [jQuery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) in a bootstrap modal with external content.
I've no problem with Firefox and Explorer, but with Chrome i've got this error
**Cannot read property 'parseMetaData' of undefined**

I include jQuery.js and jQuery.ui.min.js in main template and all other js directly in php page called by modal in this order:

```
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-video.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
```

Then there is my code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
   'use strict';
   $('#fileupload').fileupload({

        autoUpload: true,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 8000000,
        maxNumberOfFiles: 6,
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator && navigator.userAgent),
        imageMaxWidth: 1200,
        imageMaxHeight: 900,
        imageCrop: false, 
        url: '/wall/'
    });


    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );
});
```

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 2):

i found the answer!
I've to include all the scripts in the header of main template.
Bye